# Azure Active Directory not getting the refresh token any longer

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal

We have an unexpected issue:
When we are hitting endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token, we are not getting the refresh token anymore as seen in the picture attached, have not changed anything code side. It seems that this has recently stopped working on 27th November.

**Some things to note:**

- we've tried with two different application id + secret and still same issue, any ideas? Any help would greatly be appreciated.
- We've already added offline access as per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access

**I have attached the following screenshot:**

- [Postman screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq5gn.png)
- [Postman screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGPN3.png)
- [Permissions access screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GtIL.png)

---

**Update solution found:**
previously, in the authorization code, we were using the default, and it was working fine. However, something seems to be changed at the Azure Active Directory side. So we changed the request authorization code scope, and that resolved the issue.

Changed from this:

```
let URL = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=000000000-af44-44c9-a967-000000000000&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/token&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&state=12345
```

To this:

```
let url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=000000-af44-44c9-a967-00000&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/token&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `offline_access` scope when requesting the tokens? I think that's required to get refresh tokens.

Comment: Yes, I am using offline_access already. However we resolved the issue, I am updating the description now with what we did.

Comment: You can add an answer also :)

Comment: Previously, in the authorization code, we were using the default, and it was working fine. However, something seems to be changed at the Azure Active Directory side. So we changed the request authorization code scope, and that resolved the issue. And thanks @juunas for your input...

Answer (score 0):

Summarize the solution from the comments(also from OP updated in question) for communities reference:

`offline_access` is necessary in `scope` if we want to get refresh token. So just change

```
let URL = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=000000000-af44-44c9-a967-000000000000&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/token&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&state=12345
```

to

```
let url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=000000-af44-44c9-a967-00000&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/token&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345
```